# Why coordinates are shifted but not scaled

Tags: tikz-pgf, scoping, spy

I'm trying to draw on the spy'ed area

```
\documentclass[multi={tikzpicture,wrapper}]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,spy}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{8}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\largeradius}{2 * \radius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\hugeradius}{2.6 * \radius}
        \coordinate (center) at (0, 0);

        % create sector
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\addangle}{ 6 }        
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\startangle}{90 - \addangle}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\endangle}{\startangle + 2 * \addangle}

        \pgfmathsetmacro{\zoominratio}{4.5}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\preferrableSize}{5}

        \pgfmathsetmacro{\startradius}{0.35 * \radius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\endradius}{0.4 * \radius}

        \coordinate (a) at (\startangle:\startradius);
        \coordinate (c) at (\endangle:\endradius);
        \coordinate (spypoint) at ($(a)!.5!(c)$);

        \begin{scope}[spy using outlines]
            % create dA
            \draw (a)
                arc (\startangle:\endangle:\startradius) 
                -- (c)
                arc (\endangle:\startangle:\endradius)
                -- cycle;


            % Spy
            \spy[blue, circle, draw, height = \preferrableSize cm, width = \preferrableSize cm, magnification = \zoominratio, connect spies] 
                on (spypoint) in node (spyglass) at (4,3);
        \end{scope}

        \begin{scope}[shift={(spyglass.center)}, scale = \zoominratio]
            \coordinate (trypoint) at ($(c)-(spypoint)$);
            \draw[red] (trypoint) circle (.1 cm);
        \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which gives me an image [image: compiled image]

My question is regarding the next lines

```
        \begin{scope}[shift={(spyglass.center)}, scale = \zoominratio]
            \coordinate (trypoint) at ($(c)-(spypoint)$);
            \draw[red] (trypoint) circle (.1 cm);
        \end{scope}
```

The red circle is for debugging purposes. (trypoint) coordinate is calculated inside the spyglass area, i.e. it is shifted, but it is not on the vertex of "trapezoid", i.e. not scaled. Why?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a not entirely correct impression of what `scale` does. You need to really multiply the coordinate by `\zoominratio` to get what (I think) you want.

```
\documentclass[multi={tikzpicture,wrapper}]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,spy}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{8}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\largeradius}{2 * \radius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\hugeradius}{2.6 * \radius}
        \coordinate (center) at (0, 0);

        % create sector
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\addangle}{ 6 }        
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\startangle}{90 - \addangle}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\endangle}{\startangle + 2 * \addangle}

        \pgfmathsetmacro{\zoominratio}{4.5}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\preferrableSize}{5}

        \pgfmathsetmacro{\startradius}{0.35 * \radius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\endradius}{0.4 * \radius}

        \coordinate (a) at (\startangle:\startradius);
        \coordinate (c) at (\endangle:\endradius);
        \coordinate (spypoint) at ($(a)!.5!(c)$);

        \begin{scope}[spy using outlines]
            % create dA
            \draw (a)
                arc (\startangle:\endangle:\startradius) 
                -- (c)
                arc (\endangle:\startangle:\endradius)
                -- cycle;


            % Spy
            \spy[blue, circle, draw, height = \preferrableSize cm, width = \preferrableSize cm, magnification = \zoominratio, connect spies] 
                on (spypoint) in node (spyglass) at (4,3);
        \end{scope}

        \begin{scope}[shift={(spyglass.center)}, scale = \zoominratio]
            \coordinate (trypoint) at  ($\zoominratio*(c)-\zoominratio*(spypoint)$);
            \draw[red] (trypoint) circle (.1 cm);
        \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So, I don't get the calculations for free by using scope? And i should ensure to not mention anything hardcoded, or it will break on the first change?

Comment: @dEmigOd The problem is that `(c)` and `(spypoint)` are named coordinates and they are not scaled so `($(c)-(spypoint)$)` is the non-transformed vector. This is why @marmot apply the scaling to this vector. Another way to do it is `([scale=\zoominratio]$(c)-(spypoint)$)`. You can check [this question](/q/98924).

Comment: @dEmigOd Kpym already told you pretty much about this. But I do not really see the "hardcoded" problem because you were careful enough to store `\zoomratio` in a macro.